# Windows Terminal current directory address takes up all line space

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I am using Windows Terminal with PowerShell. My current working directory address is quite long and eats up most of the line (check first image below). Is there a way by which the Terminal either suppress the address to something like `.\corepy` or that I have address in one line and I can type in another line similar to what we have in Cygwin (see second image below)

[image: Windows Terminal]
[image: Cygwin Image]

Comment: The Prompts function worked. Can you put that in solution so that I can accept @DavidPostill

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My current working directory address is quite long and eats up most of the line

You need to look at changing your PowerShell prompt.

> **How-to: Set the PowerShell Prompt.**
>
> The default PowerShell prompt displays the current working directory.
>
> To display the prompt definition:
>
> ```
> (Get-Command prompt).definition
> ```
>
> The prompt function can be changed by creating a function called
> 'prompt' this can be just for the current session, or if saved in your
> profile will apply to all future sessions.

Source: [Powershell Prompt function - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-prompt.html)

> Is there a way by which the Terminal either suppress the address to something like .\corepy?

To display only the current folder use:

> ```
> function prompt {
> 'PS ' + ($pwd -split '\\')[0]+' '+$(($pwd -split '\\')[-1] -join '\') + '> '
> }
> ```

Source: [Powershell Prompt function - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-prompt.html)

---

Further Reading:

- [about_Prompts - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1)